# Emacs hangs when a file has changed on disk

Tags: windows, emacs

I'm using Emacs v24.3.1 on Windows 8.

I had a file change on disk while I had an Emacs buffer open with that file. As soon as I attempt to make a change to the buffer, a message appears in the minibuffer.

```
Fileblah.txt changed on disk; really edit the buffer? (y, n, r or C-h)
```

I would expect to be able to hit `r` to have it reload the disk version of the file, but nothing happens. Emacs completely stops responding to input. None of the listed keys work, nor do any other keys as far as I can tell. I can't `C-g` out of the minibuffer. `Alt-F4` doesn't work, not does `Close window` from the task bar. I have to kill the process from task manager.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

In cases it's various modes not playing nice with each other, for reference, my init.el is [here](https://github.com/recf/system-config/blob/master/common/.emacs.d/init.el). Nothing complex. Here's the breakdown:

- better-defaults (ido-mode, remove menu-bar, uniquify buffer `forward, saveplace)
- recentf-mode
- custom frame title
- visual-line-mode
- require final newline and delete trailing whitespace on save
- Markdown mode with auto-mode-alist
- Flyspell with Aspell backend
- Powershell mode with auto-mode-alist
- Ruby auto-mode-alist
- Puppet mode with auto-mode-alist
- Feature (Gherkin) mode with auto-mode-alist

The specific file was a markdown file with Github-flavored Markdown mode and Flyspell mode enabled.

Comment: Run `emacs -Q` and recreate the situation. That will establish whether or not your configuration is a factor.

Comment: I encountered that message on OSX running Emacs on Windows through Parallels.  Are you using a virtual machine?

Comment: Are you able to `cat` the file in question while the hang is happening? What system calls is emacs making (you can use strace to find this out)?

Comment: If you can repro the problem when starting with `emacs -Q` then consider sending a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @erjoalgo yes, I can cat the file, though given that I'm on Windows `cat` is really the powershell command `Get-Content`. I don't know enough to know how comparable that is to `cat` on *nix.

Comment: I would suggest that you `(eval-defun t)` and trace through it to determine where the hang occurs.

Comment: I have the same problem. My config is at https://github.com/fasiha/.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el and I'm on GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN, Windows 7. The overlaps I see between your setup (given the list in the question) and mine are markdown-mode, ido-mode, and remove trailing spaces. The file causing the problem is also a Markdown file (not gfm-mode, interestingly), and without flyspell, but with magit-auto-revert-mode.

Comment: After Ahmed Fasih's comment I would suggest to comment out the `markdown-mode` section in your config file and to try again.

Comment: I commented out the markdown-mode related stuff and it works, so it is definitely something with that. I would submit a patch to the project, but I tried looking at the source code for markdown-mode.el, but it's 4500 lines long and I don't know anything about mode authoring, so I'm not really sure where to start looking.

Comment: Emailed markdown-mode author Jason Blevins just now asking for suggestions, with a link to this question.

Comment: That... is smart, and I should have thought of it. Thanks for doing the leg-work.

Comment: You didn't mention which version of markdown-mode you're using (`M-x markdown-show-version`). This sounds suspiciously like a bug that was fixed in [version 1.9](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/rev-1-9). The latest version is 2.0: http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/

Comment: @JasonBlevins thanks for the note. I'm running 2.0 and the problem is still present. :(

Comment: I did not know that `markdown-show-version` existed. Thanks. I am using version 2.0 as well.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comments of the question, the problem is caused by markdown-mode, and has not been fixed as of this answer (23 April 2015).

I found [a workaround](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.emacs.help/AIy5megeSHA/vaF12ec5XYMJ) online however. I'm reproducing it here for posterity.

```
(defun leo-markdown-fontify-buffer-wiki-links-empty ()
  "Empty replacement for `markdown-fontify-buffer-wiki-links` due to hanging bug."
  (interactive))

(eval-after-load "markdown-mode"
    '(progn
       (fset 'markdown-fontify-buffer-wiki-links
             'leo-markdown-fontify-buffer-wiki-links-empty)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as debugging hangs are concerned you will have to use the emacs -Q approach to work out what's confusing the prompt. However to avoid prompting you can use 'auto-revert-mode' per-buffer or enable 'global-auto-revert-mode'.

Comment: The revert prompt feature works correctly when I run `emacs -Q`, so it's definitely something in my config. I'll dig into it more. Thanks.

Comment: @recf a good place to start is anywhere were you tweak hooks.